# Should I be explicitly checking if the first statement in my if condition is null?

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I'm trying to see what's wrong with the if statement below. Can any of you enlighten me on where there might be a case that this line could throw an error? Do I need to explicitly check if the element is null or undefined? Here's the code:

```
  const firstElement = document.querySelector('.large-image > a > img');
  const secondElement = document.querySelector('.slides > li');
  
  // This is the line I'm referring too
  if ((firstElement && firstElement.offsetWidth > 0) && firstElement.getAttribute('src') == secondElement.firstChild.getAttribute('src')) 
  return 'ELEMENT'; 
}
```

Comment: What error do you get when you run this code that you are trying to prevent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First let's reformat that line so it's readable:

```
  // This is the line I'm referring too
  if (
    firstElement &&
    firstElement.offsetWidth > 0 &&
    firstElement.getAttribute('src') == secondElement.firstChild.getAttribute('src')
  ) {
    return 'ELEMENT'
  }
```

If the element at `.slides > li` is not found on the document, then `secondElement` will be `undefined`.

And then when it gets to `secondElement.firstChild` it will crash because `firstElement` cannot be accessed on `undefined`.

So if either element might not exist on the page when this code is run, then you must check that both elements exists before accessing them.

Maybe something like:

```
  if (
    firstElement &&
    secondElement &&
    secondElement.firstChild && // couldn't hurt ¯\_(ツ)_/¯
    firstElement.offsetWidth > 0 &&
    firstElement.getAttribute('src') == secondElement.firstChild.getAttribute('src')
  ) {
    return 'ELEMENT'
  }
```

Comment: This makes sense and it works, thank you very much for the help. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `Optional chaining (?.)` to accomplish the same task by writing less code.

[Optional Chaining Operator (?.) - MDN Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining)

> The optional chaining operator (?.) enables you to read the value of a property located deep within a chain of connected objects without having to check that each reference in the chain is valid.

```
if (
  firstElement?.offsetWidth > 0 &&
  firstElement?.getAttribute('src') === secondElement?.firstChild?.getAttribute('src')
) {
  return 'ELEMENT'
}
```

Comment: This is also a great way to do it as well. Thanks.